# Js : open new window and work with it

Tags: javascript, jquery

is possible to open new window ( with external url ) with javascript or jquery and check if in that window was submited a form

something like : `window.open(....)` then : `if ( POST in new window ) { document.write('in new window was submited a form ' ); }` ..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are guaranteed to have javascript available, you might try a modal popup within the same page.

You tagged your question `jQuery` so you might want to look at some [jQuery popup modal dialogs plugins](http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/).

Being in the same page, you can control wether the form has been submitted or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the window using such code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var oWindow = 0;
function OpenWin(sURL) {
    oWindow = window.open(sURL, "_blank");
}
</script>
```

This will open the window and save reference in global variable.

If the new page is in your own domain and the form submits to different page, you can check the `oWindow.location.href` in timer e.g. every half a second, and if the location match the form action you can assume it was submitted.

If the new page is in your domain you can also hook into the form `onsubmit`, using jQuery is the most simple way - can you use it?

Comment: yes i can use jQuery. New page will have external url, not my domain

Comment: @John in case of external URL you're stuck due to obvious security reasons: any attempt to read the external contents will give you Access Denied error. I would try Alex idea of modal dialog..